# hidden property within *ngIf directive

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im using Angular2 with the Ionic Framework.

I noticed that it is not possible to use the hidden property within a *ngIf element. How can I solve it? studentid.valid is not available outside of the *ngIf element.

```
<form #studentForm="ngForm" novalidate>

  <ion-item *ngIf="useStudent">   
    <ion-label stacked> Student ID:</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="id" name="studentid" type="text" #studentid="ngModel" required></ion-input>
  <p [hidden]="studentid.valid || submitted == false" color="danger" padding-left>
         Student ID required!
      </p>  
</ion-item>  

<button ion-button block icon-right type="submit" (click)="submitForm(studentForm)">
</form>
```

Typescript:

```
 submitForm (form) {

     this.submitted = true;

      if (form.valid) {
        this.showLoading();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess problem is `[hidden]="studentid.valid || submitted == false"` gets loaded before `useStudent` is filled with value. use can also use *ngIf in p tag `<p *ngIf="useStudent" [hidden]="studentid.valid || submitted == false" color="danger" padding-left>
         Student ID required!
      </p> `

Comment: I have tried it. Seperate *ngIf statement outside of the first *ngIf statement. This caused the error: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined. It refer to studentid.valid.

Comment: `studentid?.valid`

Comment: @anshuVersatile `?.` can be used for async operation. Here studentId is a local template variable `#studentid="ngModel"`.

Comment: If you remove ngIf, does it work?

Comment: `*ngIf` from the `p` element? when it's outside of the `<ion-item *ngIf="!useVIN"> ` it always caused same error -> Cannot read property 'valid'...

Comment: No. If you remove it from top level does it still work as expected?

Comment: I need the `*ngif` in top level , because I have two input fields, but only one is visible, depending on if `useStudent` is `false` or `true`.

Comment: @micronyks `?` is not necessarily used with async.. it is the template version of a null check

Comment: @SurajRao To explain it: Two input fields, each inputfield have their own ngModel name student and name for example. But actually the user will see only one input field, depending on if he is a student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out ion-input here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/input/Input/#input-properties).

It does not have valid as an attribute. (Unless you are using form control).

You should do

```
<p [hidden]="studentid?.value||submitted == false" 
    color="danger" padding-left>
```